# bind combined with delay

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Which is better

```
some_func.bind(this,arg1,arg2,arg3).delay(4);
```

or

```
some_func.bind(this).delay(4,arg1,arg2,arg3);
```

I know that both ways will wrap things up in two layers but suppose one of the arguments lets say `arg1` is an object that is a reference from the current context, e.g. `var arg1 = this.some_obj`. Now because of all the business with pass by value, pass by reference, and function scoping will the second way not be able to recover `arg1` because when `delay` is called its context is the global object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy enough to test and both ways work well.

```
function object() {
    this.foo = function(arg) {
        document.write(this.bar+' was born on '+arg);
    }
    this.bar = 'Bob';
    this.dob = new Date();
    foo.bind(this, this.dob).delay(4);
    this.dob.setFullYear(1971);
}
object(); // start the delay
```

The date of birth is an object and so is passed by reference. You can see this happen because the year is set after the call and the delayed write shows a date in the past.

Now change the important line to `foo.bind(this).delay(4, this.dob)` and it still works!

Here's the really hard question. Why does `foo.delay.call(this, 4, this.dob)` not work?

Comment: Is that hard question for the OP?

Comment: It's for anyone really. I ask it as a matter of interest to those who have time on their hands and who are curious.

Comment: Ok, just a guess (don't have the time to test it now): after the delay, `this` no longer refers to `object` but to something else (probably `window`). Correct? BTW, I think your function call is wrong: according to [`Function#delay`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/function/prototype/delay/) the first parameter (`timeout`) has to be specified.

Comment: `delay` is a function which means it is also an object. A method of function-objects is [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) which takes it's context from the first parameter, I used `this` which is the same as binding it and calling it in one go. The remaining parameters are passed to the function-object (`delay`) being called. So the timeout is being specified after all. It should effectively be the same as `delay(4, this.dob)`.